# How to change the label text which is generated dynamically in PHP or Javascript?

Tags: label

This is code where all the labels on form generated:
$sHtml .= "\n";

For this code {$aAttrib['label']} label generated
and if add script all label will be change with same text
for this purpose we need each label div separately